# "I have a theory...". What do I really have?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I am sure we all have heard, at some point, someone saying, '*I have a theory about X. I think....*'. I have realized now that actually, a **theory** is a system of ideas that has been verified systematically (/experimentally) to be an explanation of some phenomenon, like the *theory of gravitation*. Therefore, the word should not be used so loosely as is done in popular culture today.

I realize that this meaning of theory, as 'an idea used to account for a situation or justify a course of action' is [recognized](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/theory), but especially when talking in a scientific context, it seems somewhat inappropriate to use it with that meaning - since I am using also that word for meaning something far more specific. Also, the fact that there are dozens of [websites](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/just-a-theory-7-misused-science-words/) claiming this use to be somewhat incorrect, has some significance.

Moreover, Merriam-Webster notes -

> However, there are two senses of theory which are sometimes troublesome. These are the senses which are defined as “a plausible or scientifically acceptable general principle or body of principles offered to explain phenomena” and “an unproven assumption; conjecture.”

So my question is, what would be a better replacement, in a situation where someone is trying to pose his/her "theory" about something? I was initially thinking using ***idea***, but it lacks the sense that it's supposed to be an explanation. I was also thinking something like *hypothesis* or *conjecture*, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59056/discussion-on-question-by-user1993-i-have-a-theory-what-do-i-really-have).

Comment: "I have a  theory that ..." on the Clapham omnibus would be taken as meaning "My suspicion / explanation is as follows: " 95+% of the time.

Comment: Someone saying 'my theory...' is already context enough to infer that it is their own informal personal conception of things.

Answer (score 5):

The word ***theory*** has multiple meanings.  There is the common usage which means, as you suggest, *hypothesis* or *conjecture* and there is the scientific definition which means "that's the fact, Jack."

I always use ***hypothesis*** precisely because of this so as to avoid any confusion (and am trying to teach my kids to do the same.)

Comment: 'That's the fact as received scientific wisdom sees it, Jack.' The flat-earth theory once held sway. // Always using 'hypothesis' may alienate a fair number of people. I'd argue that intelligent people should be ready to adjust register. Few would even raise an eyebrow to "I have a theory that most sightings of the Loch Ness Monster are actually catfish-, eel-, shark- or hoax-related".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I agree that intelligent people should be able to determine the meaning via context but, outside of this forum, there seems to be distressingly few such people.  The issue often comes up in the context of "evolution is *just* a theory!" which is true -- it is a theory but with the scientific meaning.  Alas, too many people, intentionally or ignorantly, apply the common usage in that context.  Hence my preference for hypothesis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Note that my comment above pertains primarily to the US; elsewhere in the world people seem to be better educated and more inclined to the use of logic.

Answer (score 2):

*Hypothesis* is good for more formal situations, as Roger Siashon says. A hypothesis is something that may become or form the basis of a theory if it's verified via measurement.

Less formally, you could use: *idea* or even *suspicion* (if you're really uncertain about it) interchangeably in your example.

Comment: thanks Benjamin, but i feel that *idea/suspicion* does not have the sense of **explanation**, as in I think X could explain this situation at hand. what do you think?

Comment: You're right for some cases. I'd put _suspicion_, _idea_, and _theory_ on a spectrum of less sure/less detailed to more sure/more detailed.

For some specific cases - where I'm proposing a way of explaining/modelling something - I often find myself using 'pattern' or 'model', as in _"If we model this as a set of x's"_ .This suggests that it's a _useful_ explanation as rather than attempting to be a _complete_ explanation. This is in a software setting though - may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: "Suspicion" as in "I have a suspicion that John murdered his wife and threw the body in a bin" is an explanation for her absence. I don't see why you need something more specific: "I have a suspicion and I think this is an explanation: John murdered his wife and threw the body in a bin" although you might say what it is an explanation for.

Answer (score 1):

I think these words can convey the sense of "supposed to be an explanation, but not verified yet":

- hypothesis
- explanation
- account
- model
- framework
- reasoning
- rationale
- justification

Or you can simply use "unverified theory"

In addition, you can also use these words, but for me they emphasize the connotation of a subjective interpretation rather than an unverified theory, though can be served as a way to explain things:

- opinion
- approach
- consideration
- assumption
- interpretation
- point of view
- perspective
- worldview

Answer (score 1):

In general conversation, instead of “I have a theory about X”.

I now say “I have a couple of ideas about X” or “I have a hypothesis as to why people think X” or “I have some thoughts about X”.

I’m not often hanging around with scientific people or colleagues, rather I simply prefer to use my words correctly, improve myself.
That, and I’m frightened by the number of mean, condescending  comment replies I’ve seen online where one individual feels the need to correct another’s  spelling or incorrect word usage.

Thank you to all of the contributors above. I really appreciated all of your responses. They went from everyday usage to academic usage, as well as discipline specific usage. Simply wonderful, each and every one. Thanks again.